# Unable to change material color at runtime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Script is unable to change material's color at runtime.

material.color or material.SetColor does not work. Objects is a pool of Gameobjects(prefab) Tried mobile-diffuse and mobile-particles-alpha blended.

```
Objects[PoolSize].GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = Color.cyan;
```

Primary goal is to be able to change alpha of material's color.

Comment: Do you have any error when you run the script?

Comment: @EhsanMohammadi no error at all. And Debug.Log(Objects[PoolSize].GetComponent<Renderer>().material.name) logs the name of the material correctly.

Comment: Ok, And do you have to use `Diffuse` or `Alpha blended` material?

Comment: @EhsanMohammadi what other mobile materials could i possibly use? It must be mobile.

Comment: Refer to [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/141106) link, there is no mobile shader which will only adjust the color of the object. You must write your own custom shader. I found a shader in GitHub. See [this](https://github.com/nylonee/unity-standard-shader-mobile) link. I hope it helps you.